# How can I get HTML source code from TWebBrowser

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, twebbrowser

How can I get source code from WebBrowser component?

I want to get source code of active page on WebBrowser component and write it to a Memo component.

Thanks.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the [`IPersistStreamInit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682273%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Interface and the [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method to store the content of the Webbrowser in a Stream.

```
Uses 
  ActiveX;

function GetWebBrowserHTML(const WebBrowser: TWebBrowser): String;
var
  LStream: TStringStream;
  Stream : IStream;
  LPersistStreamInit : IPersistStreamInit;
begin
  if not Assigned(WebBrowser.Document) then exit;
  LStream := TStringStream.Create('');
  try
    LPersistStreamInit := WebBrowser.Document as IPersistStreamInit;
    Stream := TStreamAdapter.Create(LStream,soReference);
    LPersistStreamInit.Save(Stream,true);
    result := LStream.DataString;
  finally
    LStream.Free();
  end;
end;
```

Comment: How can we make it work the REVERSE way: SetWebBrowserHTML, thus re-injecting the previously extracted code back to WebBrowser (or TEmbeddedWebBrowser). I imagine the following situation: A memo component gets the HTML source code with GetWebBrowserHTML, then the user makes some changes to the source code, then the changed source code is re-injected back into WebBrowser. This would make a nice HTML editor with real-time preview in the browser!

Comment: Better: `LStream := TStringStream.Create('', TEncoding.UTF8);`

Comment: @user1580348If you wanted to "reverse" it, all you need to change is LPersistStreamInit.Save to LPersistStreamInit.Load and initialize the TStringStream with something (or pass in a different stream).

Answer (score 6):

That works well too:

```pascal
    uses MSHTML;

    function GetHTML(w: TWebBrowser): String;
    Var
      e: IHTMLElement;
    begin
      Result := '';
      if Assigned(w.Document) then
      begin
         e := (w.Document as IHTMLDocument2).body;
    
         while e.parentElement <> nil do
         begin
           e := e.parentElement;
         end;
    
         Result := e.outerHTML;
      end;
    end;
```

Comment: Wrong. this will get you the DOM representation of the `document` element. It will not be the HTML source code.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was using it just to parse some data available on html source and using DOM representation was ok for that.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer, It's useful in any case. I also use a similar method in our spider to manipulate/parse HTML from a foreign web site.

Comment: I had to up vote this because the page I was trying to get source code had the content changed by JavaScript, so @rruz suggestion didn't work as it returned the original HTML instead of the changed one. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This has been asked and answered many times in the Embarcadero forums, with plenty of code examples posted. Search the archives.

The gist of it is that you `Navigate()` to the desired URL and wait for the `OnDocumentComplete` event to fire, then `QueryInterface()` the `Document` property for the `IPersistStreamInit` interface and call its `save()` method. Create a `TStream` object instance, such as a `TMemoryStream`, wrap it in a `TStreamAdapter` object, and then pass the adapter to `save()`. You can then load the `TStream` into the `TMemo` as needed.

Answer (score 2):

Why not Quick and Dirty:

```
OnNavigateComplete2()

Form1.RichEdit1.Text:=(WebBrowser1.OleObject.Document.documentElement.outerhtml);
```

Comment: This simple version works much better on UTF-8 encoded pages with non-ASCII text.