# How to capture content string on TWebBrowser in Delphi-xe4 mobile?

Tags: ios, delphi, delphi-xe4, twebbrowser

How to access the html content of `TWebBrowser` component on iOS?

I've checked answers on [similar question for desktop applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091666/how-can-i-get-html-source-code-from-twebbrowser). They don't seem to work for mobile.

The component `TWebBrowser` for FireMonkey OS does not contain the `WebBrowser.Document` property.

How do I proceed? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get HTML source code from TWebBrowser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091666/how-can-i-get-html-source-code-from-twebbrowser)

Comment: Is not duplicated.
That link you cited is TWebBrowser for desktop applications, which contains the property "webbrowser.documment". But for FireMonkey iOS, this property is absent.

Comment: Oops. I'm terribly sorry. I didn't get the details. I'll definitely nominate this question for reopening.

Comment: thank you for rewriting my question.